# setLookAndFeel() gives NullPointerException if I use JTable

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtable, uimanager

I have a `JFrame` with two panels. And I am setting the `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName())` in a class which extends `JFrame`.So It works fine for both panels If I dont've `JTable` in it. But If I add `JTable` to any panel then going to that panel gives me `NullPointerException` like below.

So what is the problem here, am I need to set anything for `JTable` also

EDIT: I figured it out that the problem is not with JTable but with tableCellRenderer. I am adding a tableRenderer like below

```
public class Frame extends JFrame
{
public void initialize()
{
    try
    {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.add(new JLabel("Panel1"));
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JTable table = new JTable(2,2);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxRenderer()); // Adding this renderer creates me problem
    JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    jScrollPane.setSize(100, 100);
    panel2.add(jScrollPane);
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Panel1", panel1);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Panel2", panel2);
    add(tabbedPane);
    setSize(400, 400);
    setVisible(true);
}

class CheckBoxRenderer implements TableCellRenderer
{
    JCheckBox   check   = new JCheckBox();

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object obj, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        if (row != 0 && obj instanceof Boolean)
        {
            check.setSelected((Boolean) obj);
            return check;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    frame.initialize();
}

 }
```

So this gives me NullPointerException. And If I remove the setCellRenderer line it works fine. Can someone help me out

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:685)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:581)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:365)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:276)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:779)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1055)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:731)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5232)
at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1249)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5180)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4991)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:808)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1677)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

EDIT2: On googling I found this [NullPointerException at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthContext.getPainter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111042/nullpointerexception-at-javax-swing-plaf-synth-synthcontext-getpainter).

And If I do `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");` which works fine. But I am using Ubuntu OS so I need GTK look. So I did `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("ccom.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel");` but this again gives me the exception. I can't figure it out what is wrong here. I came to know about these packages from the actual implementation of `getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`

Comment: It's impossible to know what's happening without some more detail.  I'd recommend adding the JDK source code to your path and stepping through the paintCell() method with a debugger.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson will you checkout my edited code once

Comment: I cannot reproduce the NPE with that code on Windows.  What OS are you seeing the error occur on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine for me now

```
class CheckBoxRenderer implements TableCellRenderer
{
    JCheckBox   check   = new JCheckBox();

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object obj, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        if (row != 0 && obj instanceof Boolean)
        {
            check.setSelected((Boolean) obj);
        }
//      return null; this line gives NullPointerException
        return check;
    }
}
```

Finally, I figured out the problem. The problem is with the above line `return null`. Returning `null` is giving the `NullPointerException`. Because if we see the implementation of

`private void paintCell(SynthContext context, Graphics g, Rectangle cellRect, int row, int column)` of `SynthTableUI.class` it has a line as

`Color b = component.getBackground();` but because I am returning `null`, it is trying to get the `background` of `null`. That is what the actual problem is. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 2):

Your question miss of several useful information like : Version of the JVM, Operating System...

I've encountered a similar problem in the past and it was related to a BUG of that specific JVM version, so have you updated to the latest JVM version ?

Take a look at [this post](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=118372).

I'm assuming that your JTable is not customized with anything and no event handler is present on that ...

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit And java version "1.7.0_80",
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15),
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: Try with the latest Oracle JVM 1.8.45