# Java FlatLaf - NullPointerException when serializing TableModel on another Thread while UI is visible

Tags: java, swing, model, nullpointerexception, jtable

A NullPointerException is thrown when trying to serialize a TableModel object while the associated JTable object is visible in a JFrame. I created a minimal, reproducible Example and will also include the Stack-Trace.

This is the NullPointerException reason:

```
Cannot invoke "javax.swing.CellRendererPane.paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics, java.awt.Component, java.awt.Container, int, int, int, int, boolean)" because "this.rendererPane" is null
```

I hope someone can help. Maybe the stack trace below helps to understand it better.

I am using AdoptOpenJDK14 (14.0.2.12-hotspot)

Here is the minimal, reproducible Example:

Serialization.java (Entrypoint of the Program)

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

import com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatDarkLaf;

public class Serialization {

    enum SERIALIZATION_THREAD {
        MAIN,
        THREAD,
        EDT
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Create GUI with frame and model
        UI ui = new UI();

        // Serialize the table model
        System.out.println("SERIALIZING ON MAIN THREAD");
        sleep(1000);
        serialize(ui.model, SERIALIZATION_THREAD.MAIN); // DOESN'T WORK

        System.out.println("SERIALIZING ON SEPARATE THREAD");
        sleep(1000);
        serialize(ui.model, SERIALIZATION_THREAD.THREAD); // DOESN'T WORK

        System.out.println("SERIALIZING ON EDT");
        sleep(1000);
        serialize(ui.model, SERIALIZATION_THREAD.EDT); // WORKS
    }

    public static void serialize(Serializable object, SERIALIZATION_THREAD thread) {
        switch (thread) {
            case MAIN:
                serialize0(object);
                break;
            case THREAD:
                new Thread(() -> serialize0(object)).start();
                break;
            case EDT:
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> serialize0(object));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void serialize0(Serializable object) {
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("some.dat"))) {
            oos.writeObject(object);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void sleep(int ms){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class UI {

    JFrame frame;
    MyAbstractModel model;

    public UI() throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {

        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
            FlatDarkLaf.setup(); // When using FlatLaf, it causes a NullPointer when serializing.

            model = new MyAbstractModel();
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.add(new JTable(model));
            frame.setSize(300, 300);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            System.out.println("Done Building GUI");

        });
    }
}

class MyAbstractModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAbstractModel() {
        list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return rowIndex + "-" + columnIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return "Column " + column;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

This is the Stacktrace I got.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.CellRendererPane.paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics, java.awt.Component, java.awt.Container, int, int, int, int, boolean)" because "this.rendererPane" is null
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2191)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2092)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1888)
> at com.formdev.flatlaf.ui.FlatTableUI.paint(FlatTableUI.java:397)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:797)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5255)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedImpl(RepaintManager.java:1643)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1618)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1556)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5203)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5013)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:865)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1884)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JTable.getColumnModel()"
> because "this.table" is null
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTableUI.java:1768)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1680)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.setWidthsFromPreferredWidths(JTable.java:3205)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.doLayout(JTable.java:3117)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1722)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1657)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:745)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:743)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(RepaintManager.java:742)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1883)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
> Done

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5111042/522444)

Comment: You still miss the point about ALL Swing components being created on the EDT. This would include setting the LAF and creating the table. I also don't know why you have a synchronized list. Swing is single threaded. If you correctly do all updates to the model and components on the EDT there is no need for a synchronized List. Don't know if it will fix any of the problems, the but code should follow Swing conventions.

Comment: please format the stacktrace as code to make it readable

Answer (score 0):

@camickr is right. Indeed if you initiate your gui like this, with gui components being created on the EDT, your problem disappears. Note the pattern and always use it. I don't think the problem had anything to do with serialization but feel free to tell me otherwise after you've reinstated the serialization code that I removed.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatDarkLaf;

public class Serialization extends JFrame {

    public void setGui() {
        FlatDarkLaf.setup(); // When using FlatLaf, it causes a NullPointer when serializing.

        MyAbstractModel model = new MyAbstractModel();
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        getContentPane().add(table);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Serialization f = new Serialization();
                    f.setGui();
                    f.setSize(200, 200);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class MyAbstractModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAbstractModel() {
        list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return rowIndex + "-" + columnIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return "Column " + column;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Following your refinements, I took the liberty of changing `main` to the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Create GUI with frame and model
    UI ui = new UI();
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        SERIALIZATION_THREAD t = SERIALIZATION_THREAD.valueOf(args[i]);
        // Serialize the table model
        System.out.printf("Serializing on thread %s%n", args[i]);
        serialize(ui.model, t);
        sleep(1000);
    }

}
```

and found that, corresponding with my own investigations, the *only* argument you can pass without failure is EDT. It would seem that the internal reference to the table in `BasicTableUI` 'goes null'. Not sure why but it looks like threading is involved.

Comment: Ok, I also played around a bit, it seems like having both the Table model and the serialization code inside the EDT fixes the problem. I created a static serialize method that serializes in a new thread, but this causes the error too. The issue seems to happen when trying to serialize the model from another thread. I first thought that a TableModel is not a Swing component but more like an actual model object which holds data. That's why I didn't put all of the code into the EDT. I wonder if there is a way to serialize in another thread (e.g. when adding a shutdown hook).  Thank you.

Comment: OK. Despite this being the 'correct' way to do things, there *is* still a problem which arises when trying to serialize the model. Even when that operation *is* done in a dedicated thread. Could be a bug in the LAF (problem disappears with the default LAF) - not too sure at the moment.

Comment: @Nur1 *The issue seems to happen when trying to serialize the model from another thread* - where is your [mre] demonstrating the problem. Saving data from a model should not affect the painting of the component. I don't have access to your LAF so I can't test but maybe if  I see some code I can spot an obvious problem like I suggested here.

Comment: @Nur1. Thanks for the update. Please see mine

Comment: Thanks for the additional conclusion of yours. Yes, kinda weird behavior, I never thought that threading breaks or nulls any objects.

Comment: Well it could be a bug nonetheless, even though it's *apparently* connected with threading issues. You should probably report it to the LAF authors